# .Net core - Nuget restore with Runtime files

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a C# project (.Net 6 class library) that loads powershell host and executes some powershell commands. The project has "runtimes" added as part of the other package references.

[image]

When I reference this Powershell project as a "Project Reference" in other projects, the "runtimes" content is getting copied as Modules in the bin folder and the application is working fine [image]

**Issue**: When I package the Powershell project as Nuget package and add the project, the "runtimes" content are NOT restored as part of build and the powershell script execution fails.

What do I need to do in order for the Nuget package to restore the "runtimes"?

I tried runtime in the reference project file as mention here [Include Dependency Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) and it is not working.